# NodeJS. Загрузка файла с кириллицей в имени

Tags: node.js, fileupload, кириллица

Использую nodejs express для простой api.
При загрузка файлов с кириллицей в имени, например 'Test Тест.jpg', мне приходит имя 'Test "5AB.jpg'. Просто текстовые поля приходят нормальными.
Тестирую запрос через postman.

Использовал библиотеку express-fileupload, multer. Пытался перекодировать имя через iconv. Добавлял charset в заголовки. Пытался отправлять с macos, windows.
Но нормальное имя файла так и не приходит.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение или в какую сторону копать.

UPD. Пока что решил переименовывать на фронте в unicode, а на беке переводить обратно, соответственно с помощью encodeURI и decodeURI. Вроде отрабатывает корректно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем уже при работе с полноценным фронтом (в конкретном случае NuxtJs) все отрабатывает нормально.
Возможно это была проблема с Postman. Следовательно, лучше проверить метод с помощью еще какой нибудь утилиты, либо вообще через curl.